# bash to create new directory by date followed by identifier and additional subdirectories

Tags: bash

I have a `bash` that downloads a list and if that list has data in it then a new main directory is created (with the date) with several subdirectories (example1, example2, example3).  My question is in that list there are portion of specific file types (`.vcf.gz`) - identifier towards the end that have an identifier in it that I would like to use a subdirectory. The identifier is also at the beginning of the `.bam`. The identifiers in this case are `IonXpress_001, IonXpress_002, and IonXpress_003`).  The data in the list (`identifiers`) will be different each time and the order may also be different but the naming structure within the list file will always be consistent. Is this possible,  I am not able to figure it out.  Thank you :).

**bash that produces current structure**

```
    wget -q --user=xxx --password=xxx --xxxx \
    xxxx://www.xxx.com/xxx/xxxxx/xxxx/list
    line_no=$(awk '{x++} END {print x}' /home/cmccabe/list) # count new files and store as variable
    if [[ -s /home/user/list ]]; then
    DATE=`date +%-m-%-d-%Y` 
    mkdir -p /home/user/Desktop/xxx/xxx/$DATE/{example1,example2,example3} # make new directory and subfolders
```

**current structure**

Date is the main directory with each of the examples being a sub-directory within Date.

```
Date - example1, example2, example3
```

**list**

```
IonXpress_001_R_2016_02_11_11_51_07_user_Proton-34-160210_Lurie_MedExome_Hi-Q_Auto_user_Proton-34-160210_Lurie_MedExome_Hi-Q_84.bam
IonXpress_002_R_2016_02_11_11_51_07_user_Proton-34-160210_Lurie_MedExome_Hi-Q_Auto_user_Proton-34-160210_Lurie_MedExome_Hi-Q_84.bam
IonXpress_003_R_2016_02_11_11_51_07_user_Proton-34-160210_Lurie_MedExome_Hi-Q_Auto_user_Proton-34-160210_Lurie_MedExome_Hi-Q_84.bam
TSVC_variants_IonXpress_001.vcf.gz
TSVC_variants_IonXpress_002.vcf.gz
TSVC_variants_IonXpress_003.vcf.gz
```

**desired output**

Date is the main directory with the identifier as a subdirectory within Date and each of the example are subdirectories within the identifier.

```
`Date - Identifier - example1, example2, example3
 2-13-2015 (main directory) - IonXpress_001 (identifier as a sub-directory within 2-13-2015) - example1, example2, example3 (all sub-directories within the identifier).
```

Comment: Just a recommendation: use `%Y-%m-%d` formatting for date values and avoid a whole class of headaches sorting dated files. Good luck on your problem.

Comment: `The data in the list (identifiers) will be different each time`:  Crucial to understanding your question is ,  different precisely how? IonXpress appears to be a brand name for scientific barcoding equipment and unlikely to change, however I don't want to presume. What other identifier values could it be? Just `IonXpress_(3digits)`, or are you using other products/brands? thanks

Comment: you are correct in that the brandname is IonXpress_(3digits).  That naming structure will always be the same (IonXpress_001 or IonXpress_010)... what will change is the text after the (3digits)_ for the `.bam` files.  In the `.vcf.gz` files the only thing that will change are the (3digits) so that type may be easiest to use.  For example, in the case of`TSVC_variants_IonXpress_001.vcf.gz` compared to `TSVC_variants_IonXpress_002.vcf.gz, only the digits changed while the text remains the same. Does this help.  Thank you :).